# Diagnosing a 404 error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, http-status-code-404

I am trying to make a POST request to `/api/kpi?data=some+stuff`:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1:9010/api/create_kpi -F data="some stuff"
```

but I'm getting a 404.

My routes are:

```
# config/routes.rb

namespace :api do
  resource :kpi,  :except => [:edit, :destroy]
end
```

Which should hit my controller

```
# app/controllers/api/kpi_controller.rb

class Api::KpiController < ApplicationController
  def create
    temp = Kpi.new(params[:data])
  end
end
```

So I am guessing the paths are not correct.  Right?  I am having a hard time understanding whether my route is incorrect, or the controller, or the call.

Comment: Running `rake routes` will show you how your routes go. Verify it leads where you expect.

Comment: @jonallard ok, trying it now...my rake is apparently having version problem issues...resolving those now :)

Comment: Psssst... I don't know what your situation is, but `bundle install` + [this here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7553276/720164) (in case) might help

Comment: @jonallard I just removed the duplicate rake gem, and rank rake routes, but I got this error: rake aborted!
undefined method `field' for Kpi:Class

Comment: `Kpi:Class` points to your model. It looks like you included a method `field` in there. Can you verify that syntax? Fields are usually contained on the database/schema side.

Comment: @jonallard I just posted my model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11990/discussion-between-jonallard-and-geekedout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get a 404, check your routes. It usually means there is no route to the controller to reach. Routes are what makes the link between URLs and controllers. If your controller was getting hit, it'd either work or give you a runtime error.

1. [Inspect your routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes) by running `rake routes`. It's a very helpful tool. It should give you something like this:

   ```
       users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
   ```

   You can see that it gives you the mapping of what `[method, URL]` request will hit which `[controller, action]`. For example, here, `POST /users` will trigger action `create` of `UsersController`.
2. Given a controller/resource name, Rails will, by [convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), go looking for the plural of that name. For example, given `resources :user`, Rails will go looking for `UsersController` in file `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`. (Path/file names have to match the name!)

   @yfedblum [talks about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615194/720164) the use of singular and plural in Rails into more detail.