# Rails 3 edit_path method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

sorry if this is a dumb Q, this is my first Rails3 project...

For some reason, this `<%= link_to 'edit', edit_geofence_path(geofence) %>`

renders as `<a href="/geofence/edit.2">edit</a>` (my geofence's id is 2).

And `<%= link_to 'delete', {:action=>'destroy', :id=>geofence}, :confirm=>"You sure?", :method=> :delete %>`

renders as `<a href="/geofence?id=2" data-confirm="You sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">delete</a>`,

which might be fine, but clicking the link generates this in the logs `Started GET "/geofence?id=2"`.  So, not DELETE, just GET.

My routes.rb file is just `resource :geofence`.

On a related note, for some reason the default action for a geofence is "show".  So /geofence/ DOES NOT call the index method, it calls the show method.  I think that also must be wrong.

I'm done cursing at this app for now, I'm going to take a day to cool off and hopefully get this SIMPLE SCAFFOLD working tomorrow night...   Help me, stackoverflow!  You're my only hope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'delete', {:action=>'destroy', :id=>geofence}, :confirm=>"You sure?", :method=> :delete %>
```

should be:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', {:action=>'destroy', :id=>geofence}, :confirm=>"You sure?", :method=> :delete, :remote => true %>
```

Without :remote => true, the click isn't handled by javascript.

And in your routes.rb file, you should have that defined as:

```
resources :geofence
```

Setting it as resource implies that there is only one, and is causing a lot of your weird behavior.

Comment: just wanted to add that with if you run rake routes in your terminal you should be able to see whats going on.  resource :geofence will create a route that looks like /:controller/:action/.:format - no id parameter is expected, hence when you try to pass one (in this case 2) it gets interpreted as a format thing.  resources :geofence will give you /:controller/:action/:id

Comment: oh my god, the internet's hivemind solved my problem in less time than it took me to fail in the first place.   stack overflow is incredible!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, to complete *ctide* answer I would suggest you to use the plural form of your controllers name as a convention. It will sound more natural to put:

```
resources :geofences
```

inside your *routes.rb* file.

Here is a [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646951/singular-or-plural-controller-and-helper-names-in-rails), about using the plural form as a convention for controllers.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `resource :geofence` in your routes file you are telling your application that there is *only one* geofence resource, and that it is not a collection.  You will get `show`, `update`, `create`, `new`, but not `index` - and the `id` value will not be used because there is only one resource.  (The `show` action here will have the path `/geofence`

If you use `resources :geofences` (notice the pluralization) then you've defined a collection of resources, `/geofences` will now give you the `index` action and your url helpers will work correctly with the show action rendering `/geofences/3`.

Hope this helps you understand why the plural form is necessary for this sort of resource :)