# rails singular resource still plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes, singular

I have a search route which I would like to make singular but when I specify a singular route it still makes plural controller routes, is this how it's supposed to be?

```
resource :search
```

Gives me

```
 search POST        /search(.:format)        {:action=>"create", :controller=>"searches"}
 new_search  GET    /search/new(.:format)    {:action=>"new", :controller=>"searches"}
 edit_search GET    /search/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"searches"}
             GET    /search(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"searches"}
             PUT    /search(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"searches"}
             DELETE /search(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"searches"}
```

Plural controller "searches"

I only have one route really... to create a search:

So I did:   `match "search" => "search#create"`

I'm just wondering for the future if I'm still supposed to keep the controller plural?  Rails 3.0.9

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, that's how it's supposed to be. Quote from the Rails Guide on Routing:

> Because you might want to use the same controller for a singular route
>   (/account) and a plural route (/accounts/45), singular resources map
>   to plural controllers.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Comment: ah ok, also I still need to specify @search + :url => search_path or the form_for won't work on a singular route?

Comment: I would expect it to work without the :url parameter. But just try it out I suppose.

Comment: You can do `resource :search, :controller => :search`.

Comment: On a side note, I have a model called "dives" and rails made the singular "dife" which is not correct. To fix this, I had to update the Infections.rb file with "inflect.irregular 'dive', 'dives'". Now routes are correctly /dive/new instead of /dife/new.

Answer (score 27):

You could fix this by setting the plural of "search" to be uncountable so in config/initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.uncountable %w( search )
end
```

This should now allow search to only be used

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seemed to be the easiest way to avoid the singular/plural confusion. The singular/plural distinction might make sense when a controllers is associated with a model, as per the Rails convention, but when that's not the case, I see no sense for Rails automagically pluralizing identifiers.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you use the overridden word anywhere else it will no longer be correctly pluralized.

Comment: Making a global change to fix a local issue doesn't usually end well. Now, `search` will not get pluralized anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 7):

Do you want only one route to be generated for the creation?

If so:

```
resource :search, :only => :create
```

The fact that the controller for the REST resource is named searches_controller is a convention (that you can change, by forcing the controller's name in the route with `resource :search, :only => :create, :controller => :search`, but it does not worth it...).

Answer (score 6):

Is the search really a resource? If it is, then what you a creating is an instance of a model with a type of "search", in which case the plural controller "searches" makes perfect sense.

However, if it's a controller that doesn't have multiple models, then maybe not. In which case, you don't need to define the routes with `resource :search` you can simply use `get 'search/create'` to tell the router to answer "search/create" to the 'create' action in your 'search' controller.