# Rails HomeController singular or plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've been configuring my [devise installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513066/devise-with-rails-4) and I came upon the line of:

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

From my understanding, I thought [controllers were to be named plural.](http://cani.saure.us/?p=48) Is HomeController just an exception to the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although that tutorial is very good, you have to remember Devise does not mind what your controllers are called (FYI)

Neither does Rails actually. However, it's defaulted to be plural. You can get around it by using singular routing resources ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939688/rails-singular-resource-still-plural)), but it's not a big deal

We've used singular controller names before with no issues. It's singular model names which are the most important

Answer (score 2):

It is, the plural rule applies so as to differentiate your Model names from your Controllers, I guess you do not have a Class called Home do you?