# routing error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a basic Rails project called Book_shelf. It contains a controller called home.
Inside the home controller I have defined an action called index.
But when I try to run this application in the browser it gives me a routing error.

I am using this url to type in the browser:
http://localhost:3000/home/index

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked routes.rb to make sure that there is a route for your controller?

Comment: what exactly is the error message you are getting?  How are you starting your sever and what does the sever window show when the web page gets the error.

Comment: My routes.rb file is as follows:           BookShelf::Application.routes.draw do
   root :to => "home#index"
end

Comment: When I try to run this application using "rails server" command it gives me with the error: Routing error (no route matches "/home" )

Answer (score 0):

The `index` action for `home` is by default located at `http://localhost:3000/home/`, there is no need to write `index` after that.

If you type `index`, rails assumes you are trying to use the `show` action for a `home` with an id of `index`, which of course will not exist since by default `ids` will be numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quickie before the answer , As per `Rails` convention controller names must be plural please ref :[Singular or plural controller and helper names in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646951/singular-or-plural-controller-and-helper-names-in-rails)

Assuming that the controller name is `homes_controller.rb`
in `routes.rb` add a route says `resources :homes`, if you do a scaffold routes will be added by the generators

Step 1: Please look out for the available routes by `rake routes`, you might get up like 
`Prefix   Verb     URI Pattern              Controller#Action
homes     GET    /homes(.:format)             homes#index
          POST   /homes(.:format)             homes#create
new_home  GET    /homes/new(.:format)         homes#new
edit_home GET    /homes/:id  /edit(.:format)  homes#edit
home      GET    /homes/:id(.:format)         homes#show
          PATCH  /homes/:id(.:format)         homes#update
          PUT    /homes/:id(.:format)         homes#update
          DELETE /homes/:id(.:format)`

You can find the controller and its mapped action.

Step 2: You can directly access `index` action, http://localhost:3000/homes ('/index') is default
 
ref: `homes     GET    /homes(.:format)    homes#index`
 
Step 3: (if above doenst work) You can backtrace the error from the live termination on the browser if the problem persist when using Rails4