# Rails Model and Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

I generated a controller called Search. later I built a model called search as well. When i try to make a search i get an error that says there is no controller called searches, so it looks like it the model interacts with the plural of itself by default. how do i change this behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are quite new to rails.  The best advice here is almost certainly "don't"  Rails uses a lot of conventions to avoid having to configure everything, and this is one of them.  So I would recommend changing the name of your controller rather than trying to make rails do something out of the ordinary

for more detail see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646951/singular-or-plural-controller-and-helper-names-in-rails)

Comment: Excellent advice. Convention over configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the controller class from 'SearchController' to 'SearchesController'. Also rename the file in `apps/controllers` to from `search_controller.rb` to `searches_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have generated controller and model separately, you also generated additional files like test files, views and so on. So potentially you will have big headache on this.

I would recommend to use `rails destroy` command in these steps:

Commit your current project (later you can recover your content from it)

Run this commands:

```
rails destroy model Search
rails destroy controller Search
```

Restore your controller and model from previous commit.