# No method error in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm playing with Rails at the moment and building a basic app. When I try to run the app I get this error:

"undefined method `products_path' for #<#:0x45c19f8>"

My code is as follows...

Config:

```
Depot::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :product
  resources :test
end
```

Controller:

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h1>Page to add new products</h1>

<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>

    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>

    <%= f.submit "Create new product" %>
<% end %>
```

I don't understand why the form won't render and I receive the error message. Am I missing something?

Thanks any help appreciated.

Edited to add config file.

Comment: Show your config/routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line in config/routes.rb

```
resources :products
```

Comment: I tried using "resources :products" and "resources :product". Neither works.

Comment: The problem is your controller is not plural it should class ProductsController < ApplicationController

Comment: I realised I should have made it plural after I had done it. Can I not name it whatever I like? Is it the case that if the Controller is not named in the plural the app cannot work?

Comment: Yeah its a rails convention that controller names will always be pluralized. You can name it whatever you like but it should be pluralized.

Comment: OK, so how can I make mine work considering that I have named my Controller as a singular rather than plural?

Comment: Hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646951/singular-or-plural-controller-and-helper-names-in-rails