# Is using collection option in rails routing means resources should be plural?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I was reading through the blog post [Authentication with Warden, devise-less](http://pothibo.com/2013/07/authentication-with-warden-devise-less), but one thing in that post is how he approaches the routing. So which one is more logical:
the authors way

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    # Registrations is set as plural, which means that each user can make many 
    # registrations, and open many sessions and so will make many confiramtions
    resource :registrations, only: [:show, :create]
    resource :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resource :confirmations, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

my way

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    # Their is only one registration for each user, so why we use it in plural
    resource :registration, only: [:show, :create]
    # the same with session and confirmation
    resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    resource :confirmation, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

I am a little confused about the collection and member features in rails routing, so which one is more logical.

Answer (score 0):

Since a resource more or less equals a controller in the Rails world and controllers [should have plural names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646951/3340665) I would vote for the authors version.