# Add locales to Singular controller in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I have a singular controller i want to add locales to that. It looks like

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end

   def markdown_syntax
   end
 end
```

And my `about.en.yml` looks like

```
en:
 about:
   home:
    discover_message: 'Discover, Track and Compare Open Source'
    join_now: 'Join Now'
    whats_new: "What's New"
    popular_projects: 'Most Popular Projects'
    active_projects: 'Most Active Projects'
```

I am getting translation missing error because it doesn't recognizing from `about.en.yml`

Error Message:

```
translation missing: en.about.home.discover_message
```

Comment: Post the exact error msg. What is the full path of your `about.en.yml`?

Comment: Please look at that error message

Answer (score 0):

By default Rails is going to look for `en.yml` in the `config/locales` directory.

If you're using `about.en.yml` as the filename, then Rails is not going to find it unless you've configured things otherwise.

Comment: I have my .yml in locales folder only.Its loading but not applying the changes. It works works fine for plural name controller(s) like abouts,en,yml.  After changing it to about.en.yml , it is not able to recognize.

Comment: Are you restarting the rails server every time you change the locale file? If not, the changes won't get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify name of the controller in the locale file like this:

```
en:
  controllers:
    about:
      home:
        discover_message: 'Discover, Track and Compare Open Source'
        join_now: 'Join Now'
        whats_new: "What's New"
        popular_projects: 'Most Popular Projects'
        active_projects: 'Most Active Projects'
```

I have also changed 1 space indentation to 2 space indentation, which is standard.