# Created new controller, error in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new controller "user" with the actions register and index. However when I go on my browser to http://localhost:3000/user/register i get an error. It tells me `No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"user"}`

Did I not create the controller correctly?

Here's some of my code.

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'user/index'

  get 'user/register'

  get 'site/index'

  get 'site/about'

  get 'site/help'

  root 'site#index'
```

**User Controller**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def register
    @title = 'Register'
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
it keeps telling me there is a problem with the line between the ***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= @title %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="whole_page">
  <div id="header">Work<b>Link</b></div>
  <div id= "nav">
    <%= link_to_unless_current'Home', action: 'index' %> |
    ***<%= link_to_unless_current'About', action: 'about' %> |***
    <%= link_to_unless_current'Help', action: 'help' %>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= @content %>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch your routes/controllers to the following. Also, keep your controller names plural.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def register
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: %w(index) do
  get :register, on: :collection
end
```

I specified `on: :collection`, because the route doesn't *belong* to a **member** of the collection. ie: it doesn't need an object's ID, like `users/1/` would. The other option is `member`, which of course is a route that belongs to a **member** of the collection.

Now, visit localhost:3000/users/register.

- [Here is a good read](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) on routing with Rails.
- [Here is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646956/2456549) on the plural naming convention.

Comment: it is still giving me a routing error: uninitialized constant UsersController

Comment: did you change your file name to `users_controller.rb` instead of `user_controller.rb`?

Comment: Yeah I did that. But now it keeps telling me  `<%= link_to_unless_current'About', action: 'about' %> | ` when I refresh my browser.

Comment: I don't know what that means. Can you paste the full stack trace? What file is the error coming from?

Comment: I added an  update to my post with the issue it keeps bringing up.

Answer (score 0):

your routes.rb file should also have plural naming. This answer supports Justin's answer.

so this line for example:

```
user/register
```

should be

```
users/register
```

you might end up in get errors which you have to fix but if my suggestion works. then you are good to go.

Based on your update
do you have an about method defined???